# Java ANTLR 4. Generated parser doesn't recognize anything

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, lexer

I am writing a lexer and parser to my own language to process operations on lists. I started with that:

```
 list_Declaration : L_LIST L_ID ASSIGN LBRACE NUMBER (COMA  NUMBER)* RBRACE SEMI;
NUMBER          : [0-9]+;
L_BOOLEAN_LITERAL
    :   'true'
    |   'false'
    ;
L_ID            :   [a-z]+;

L_IF            : 'if';
L_ELSE          : 'else';
L_THEN          : 'then';
L_FOREACH       : 'foreach';
L_VAR           : 'var';
L_IN            : 'in';
L_LIST          : 'list';
L_NUMBER        : 'number';
L_RETURN        : 'return';

ASSIGN          : '=';

LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
LBRACE          : '{';
RBRACE          : '}';
COMA            : ',';
SEMI            : ';';
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ ->skip;
```

And when i try to parse this with example text:

```
list a = {2,3};
```

It says:

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: ''
line 1:1 missing 'list' at 'list'
line 1:6 extraneous input 'a' expecting '='
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting `L_ID` below `L_RETURN` . I think the ambiguity is the problem. The `L_ID` precedence will match any of those constants values below it

Comment: Alternatively, add `L_LETTER : [a-z]` and replace `L_ID` with parser rule `id : L_LETTER+`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this way to define lexer, and it always work:

```
fragment I : [iI];
fragment L : [lL];
fragment S : [sS];
fragment T : [tT];

L_List     : L I S T;
```

Your `'list'` has been matched as `L_ID`, so `extraneous input 'a' expecting '='`
Put your L_ID below almost all of the lexers.